# Cosa vuol dire "bugna" in questo passaggio?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Ho già detto che sugli alberi noi trascorrevamo ore e ore, e non per motivi utilitari come fanno tanti ragazzi, che ci salgono solo per cercar frutta o nidi d’uccelli, ma per il piacere di superare difficili **bugne** del tronco e inforcature, e arrivare più in alto che si poteva, e trovare bei posti dove fermarci a guardare il mondo laggiù, a fare scherzi e voci a chi passava sotto.

La mia domanda è sul significato di queste "bugne" che appaiono in questa frase. Ho cercato il termine "bugna" in parecchi dizionari, ma le accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa sono?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La bugna è un termine dialettale piemontese (usato peraltro anche in Liguria) che viene usato per indicare un nodo intricato di un albero, ma anche ad esempio per indicare un bernoccolo oppure una massa informe e tondeggiante.

Nel passaggio da te citato le bugne indicano quelle parti dell’albero dove è stato tagliato un ramo a raso del tronco e col tempo si forma una massa informe.

Un possibile sinonimo di bugna potrebbe essere il termine [bitorzolo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bitorzolo/).